# MySQL ordering SELECT by associated column

Tags: sql, mysql

I'd like to select some `Addresses` from a MySQL DB. `Addresses` can have a `Contact`, an `Organization`, or both. (A `Contact` can have many `Addresses`. So can an `Organization`.)

Let's say I want to get all of an `Organization`'s `Addresses`. That's no big deal. But what if I want to `ORDER` them by `Contact.last_name`? Some of the `Addresses` don't have a `Contact`.

I did some experimenting and discovered that if you `ORDER BY contacts.last_name`, then only those `Addresses` that have a `Contact` will be returned. I tried `ORDER BY contacts.last_name, addresses.street1`, but still only `Addresses` that had an associated `Contact` were returned.

Is there a query that will find `Addresses` by `Organization.id`, order the results by `Contact.last_name`, and include all the `Organization`'s `Addresses`, even ones that don't have a `Contact`?

---

Table structure

```
addresses
---------
id
contact_id
organization_id
street1

contacts
--------
id
last_name

organizations
-------------
id
name
```

---

Solution:

Returns **all** the `Organization`'s `Addresses`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM addresses a
LEFT JOIN contacts c
ON a.contact_id = c.id
WHERE a.organization_id = '8283'
ORDER BY c.last_name
```

---

OK, great the above query solved it.

Comment: More on the table structure or the queries you've tried would be helpful.

Comment: `ORDER BY` doesn't filter out results. The default sort is ascending (ASC) so nulls would be at the top of the list. I think you're mixing up ORDER BY with the JOIN criteria - post the query you're using.

Comment: I would urge you to refrain from adding the dummy data if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably the join and not the order-by clause. As soon as you join the `Addresses` table with the Contacts table, the join condition will eliminate all tuples with NULL values.

To avoid this, you have to use an `OUTER JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` (the default). The idea behind an `OUTER JOIN` is simply to extend the missing table rows with NULL values for processing/ordering and so on.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I didn't understand ORDER BY. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the MySQL IFNULL function to return an empty string when there is no associated contact. That way, if there is no associated contact for an address, you still get a record with an empty string in the contact column if there is no contact.

For example:

```
SELECT a.*,
IFNULL(c.last_name, '') AS last_name
FROM Addresses a
LEFT JOIN Contacts c
ON a.contact_id = c.id
ORDER BY IFNULL(c.last_name, '')
```

As others have pointed out, ORDER BY does not filter out missing records. Ensure you have the proper join in your query and it will return records even if there is no associated contact. I have added the IFNULL to return an empty string instead of a NULL, but that is only for aesthetics and doesn't actually change the number of records returned.